# Calling my own API to my mobile application

Tags: swift, xcode, postman

I'm calling my own API to my mobile application and post the value from the mobile application to my API but it doesn't work. Here is my code that call API to get the value and post the value to my API [here is the statement of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQTfm.png)my mobile application is still able to run even the value can't store to my own API.

```
let headers = [
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
      "Postman-Token": "b839d806-4bd2-4247-9451-1d006a076bf4"
    ]
    let parameters = [
      "name": name,
      "icNumber": icNumber,
      "medicineType": medicineType,
      "amount": amount
    ] as [String : Any]

    do {
        let postData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])

       let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8080/post")! as URL,
                                               cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                           timeoutInterval: 10.0)
       request.httpMethod = "POST"
       request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
       request.httpBody = postData as Data

        print("post ")

       let session = URLSession.shared
       let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
         if (error != nil) {
            print(error as Any)
         } else {
           let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
            print(httpResponse as Any)
         }
       })

       dataTask.resume()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your API is available over a non-secure protocol (http), iOS will prevent any call to it, you need either to make it secure (https) or you can add exceptions for development purposes.

To add an exception for a specific domain, add the following in your App's info.plist:

```xml
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <false/>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>your-domain-here.com</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

Replace `your-domain-here.com` with your domain.

Comment: I did add into my Info.plist but it still having the same problem.

Comment: What domain you added?

Comment: I added my own domain that is my http://localhost/post but it still can't connect. @Muhamed AlGhzawi

Comment: @Ice it should be `localhost` only.